# How to read Ajax JSON in Java (JEE)?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I'm trying to read a ajax json file in a java class. Anyone knows how to get values from there?

```
function addBook() {
    jQuery.ajex({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/book_service/rest/books/",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",  
        dataType:'json',
        data: {
            title:$("#stitle").val(),
            price:$("#sprice").val()
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            log.out("Added Successfully");
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            log.out("Error Adding");
        },
        timeout: 120000,
    });
};
```

This is my java class

```
@POST
public void addBook() {


        String title;
        int price;
        new Books().addBook(title, price);
}
```

Comment: Its not `jQuery.ajex`, its `jQuery.ajax`. And what is `log`?

Comment: What do you mean? I just want to take the values from data in addBook()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find out the solution...

annotation @Consumes with Application_JSON. Gives you to access as JSON object passing through JsonObject into the method.

In ajax you should pass the values as JSON format follows,

```
function addBook() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/book_service/rest/books",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify( {
            "bid"   :$("#sid").val(),
            "title" :$("#stitle").val(),
            "price" :$("#sprice").val()
        }),
});
```

---

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void addBook(JsonObject data) {

        int id = Integer.parseInt(data.getString("bid"));
        String title = data.getString("title");
        double price = Double.parseDouble(data.getString("price"));

        System.out.println(id+" "+title+" "+price);
```